# Yii user->checkAccess is false when auth is parent

Tags: php, yii

**NOTE:** i use Yii **1.1**
On an app i switched to db auth management to use a more complex auth system, but now i can't understand why an user with a parent role fails the check for the child role.

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Administrator')){
```

this fails for a **Superadmin** user

I'll explain myself:

I have 3 Roles: `Normal, Administrator, Superadmin`

The superadmin has 2 childs, Normal and Administrator, while administrator has 1, Normal.

Obviously every parent must be able to do everything his child can do.

Here's the code from Useridentity where i assign the role

```
...
$this->_id=$myUser->userid;
$this->setState('title', $myUser->access_level);
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

if(!$auth->isAssigned($myUser->access_level,$this->_id))
{
  if($auth->assign($myUser->access_level,$this->_id))
  {
    Yii::app()->authManager->save();
  }
}
```

In my config:

```
'authManager'=>array(
   'class'=>'CDbAuthManager',
   'defaultRoles'=>array('Normal','Administrator','Superadmin'),
 ),
```

**MORE INFO**
authassignment table content: 
itemname    userid  bizrule     data

```
Administrator   1   NULL    N;
Administrator   8   NULL    N;
Normal  2   NULL    N;
Superadmin  1   NULL    N;
```

That means the user 1 has both Administrator and Superadmin permissions. But checkAccess('Administrator') still returns FALSE

Comment: If you downvote the post, please let me know what i'm doing wrong or why the question is stupid. Otherwise i won't understand anything

Comment: How do you define childs roles?

Comment: @Skatox
$auth=Yii::app()->authManager;

$role=$auth->createRole('Administrator');

$role->addChild('Normal');

Inside the database i can see the roles and the children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i managed to get my code working.

I added 3 tasks with NULL rules:

> adminPermissions, superPermissions, normalPermissions

```
$task=$auth->createTask('adminPermissions','...description',NULL);
$task=$auth->createTask('superPermissions','...description',NULL);
$task=$auth->createTask('normalPermissions','...description',NULL);
```

and then added them as childs of the roles. (since the rule is NULL, it never returns TRUE unless is child of something).

Obviously it's better to create tasks and operations like updatePost or deleteUser, but if you started like me with simple roles and you were using CPhpAuthManager, you'll be able to change to the CDbAuthManager while the app is already in production and later you can create your tasks and operations.

Inside my app now i check for adminPermissions or superPermissions like this:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('adminPermissions')){
```

Comment: i'll wait for someone else to answer before choosing my post as the answer, i'd be happy to see you can actually have only roles and no tasks or operations.

Comment: This is the answer, select it.